# What's the difference between GlobalKey and GlobalKeyObject?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to know the difference and more importantly the real world usage difference between `GlobalKey` and `GlobalObjectKey`, when to use which and when to avoid?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only difference is how their `==` operator behaves

- [GlobalKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) is equal only to itself:

```dart
final first = GlobalKey();
final second = GlobalKey();
print(first == second); // false
```

- two [GlobalObjectKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalObjectKey-class.html)s are equal if their object is equal:

```dart
final first = GlobalObjectKey(42);
final second = GlobalObjectKey(42);
final third = GlobalObjectKey(21);
print(first == second); // true
print(first == third); // false
```

This is important because Flutter relies on comparing a Widget's `key` using `==` to see if it should preserve the state of that widget, or instead destroy the previous state and create a new one.

Their usage is slightly different.

[GlobalKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) would typically be used inside a `StatefulWidget`, or the key would be stored as a global variable:

```dart
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  // Stores the GlobalKey inside the widget State
  final key = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: key,
      child: ...
    );
  }
}
```

This approach is the most flexible way to use a use a [GlobalKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html)-like. But it is also the most verbose

[GlobalObjectKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalObjectKey-class.html) comes as a simplification to that usage. It allows using global keys inside `StatelessWidget` for slightly less verbose code, but require a unique "object".

A typical usage would be:

```dart
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final key = const GlobalObjectKey('my_form_key');
    return Form(
      key: key,
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

This is less verbose. But we need to make sure that the object passed to `GlobalObjectKey` is unique to this widget and doesn't change over time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however I still didn't understand `GlobalObjectKey` part that good.